# Repeat control refresh error

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

i have a strange problem.

I have a XPage with a repeat control where the data source is a view. 
This view has a filter by category name.
In the XPage is a button with the following script:

```
doc = session.getCurrentDatabase().createDocument();            
doc.replaceItemValue("form", "myForm");
doc.replaceItemValue("docId", "myID");
doc.save();
```

The button makes a partial refresh on the repeat control, but always on the first time clicking on the button (after opening the XPage) does not refresh the repeater. After a second click on the button, i can see two new documents.

I have the same problem when i delete a document from the view, but in this case i get the following error message:

```
javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error testing property 'label' in bean of type null
Error testing property 'label' in bean of type null
```

Any ideas how to reload the repeat control will be better (without errors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the document on the backend, so the runtime isn't aware a new document is created, and is therefore dependent upon the indexer adding the document to the view before it will be added to the refresh, which usually happens after a slight delay, which is why after the next refresh, you see two documents. The way I have solved it in the past, which is a bit hacktastic to be sure, is to perform the refresh using a setTimeout() with a bout a 300-500 ms delay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi,
and thanks for your answer.
Have you a little example for me how is works with the setTimeout?

Comment: I use this in the clientside event of the button but it does not work `setTimeout(function(){
 XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:myElement}", {});
},1000);`